# how to check if a file is compressed with gzexe in Python?

Tags: python, compression

I'm working on a simple virus scanner with Python and the scanner needs to check if a file has a virus signature(a particular string) in it. If a file is compressed, the scanner needs to decompress the file first and then check for the signature. Files that are compressed with gzip has a magic number at the very beginning of the file and that's easy to check and use gzip library to decompress.

But how to check if a file is compressed with gzexe? I looked [here](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) but gzexe compressed file is not listed. I checked the content of a file that's compressed with gzexe and find that it starts with "#!bin/sh". I think I can check this, but is there a better way to do this? Also, is there any library that can deal decompress gzexe compressed file?

**EDIT**

The previous problem I had with zlib is because I didn't realize that you have to pass a second parameter to zlib.decompress or it will give you an error. [Python zlib documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html) didn't point that out very clearly. In python it seems you need to pass 15+32 to this decompress method.

```
zlib.decompress(data, 15 + 32)
```

Also gzexe can be decompressed by zlib, As Mark said, you just need to find where the magic number starts and decompress the file from there.

Comment: Is this for homework? If not, writing your own virus scanner is not a good idea.

Comment: @user2357112 this is homework and I got the most part running by implementing aho-corasick algorithm. I just need to deal with compressed files now and I got stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just search the file for a gzip signature.  It is in there after the shell script.

You can use the [zlib](http://zlib.net/) library to decompress it.

Comment: I'll look at it. At the meantime is there a library I can use to decompress it?

Comment: You said that it's easy to check for and decompress a gzip file using the "gzip" library.  Now you're saying you don't know how?

Comment: Because I tried and it didn't work. Gave me "Not a gzipped file" error. zlib didn't even decompress gzipped file. Gave me "zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check". Did you try on your system?

Comment: Now I found that the reason zlib didn't work with gzipped file is that I didn't pass it a second parameter. But, still it can't work with gzexe compressed file.

Comment: As I said, search for the gzip signature.  Start decompressing _there_.

Comment: I just realized who answered my question. I'll be excited for a while now.